# Neumann KM185 field nature recording suitability

Tags: field-recording, field, neumann

Is a matched pair of Neumann KM185s suitable for outdoor nature recordings?

Answer (score 1):

Being hypercardioid, a KM185 with adequate wind protection would be fine recording point-sources in mono, but not really suitable for any form of stereo recording. I would use spaced omni or cardioid in ORTF myself.